# Echo result of two tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

> table course[name,departament,year,id,examinar]
>   for example:
>
> music,music Science,first,1,pr.Elias
>
> table grade[studentname,stlastname,departament,,course,yearOfcourse,grade,examinar]
>   for example:
>
> roland,doda,music Science,music,first,10,pr.Elias
>
> Now i have the below code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM course where  year ='first' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row['name']."</td>
        <td>".$row['departament']."</td>
        <td>".$row['examinar']."</td> 
        </tr>";
}
```

This works fine but that i want is into `<tr>` tags of while loop to echo out the grade from table grade?

Comment: First redesign your database. That is as _flakey_ as _the Signing Detective_ in its current form

Comment: Why it does not exist any solution?i cant redesign my DB i have a big project

Comment: thank you but i must doing that without start learning PDO i dont have time

Comment: PS: Looks like homework to me

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want, but I have had so make a few assumptions in the 
columns required to make a correct join.

I also added some error checking so that if I made an incorrect assumption you will be told about it.

```
$query = "SELECT c.*,g.grade 
          FROM course c 
              JOIN grade g ON (     g.departament = c.departament
                                AND g.year = c.year
                                AND g.course = c.name                        
                            )
          WHERE c.year ='first' ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ( $result === false ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    echo "<tr>
        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['departament']}</td>
        <td>{$row['examinar']}</td> 
        <td>{$row['grade']}</td> 
        </tr>";
}
```

> Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
>   is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: Thank you but i get this error : Unknown column 'g.grade' in 'field list'

Comment: Or on "JOIN grade ON" maybe  be "JOIN grade g ON"  right?

Comment: Yup well spotted, my typo sorry FIXED It

Comment: _May i add column grade on table course?_ No it makes no sence in that table.

Comment: Ok i had fixed it thanks but this code return me an empty result!
I check that doing if (!$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo "wrong"}

Comment: Would be useful to have a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to play with that has a few test columns in both tables